# How to modify drawable corners programmatically Android Java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I need to modify an xml drawable corner radius programmatically from Java.

XML looks like this (can be modified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="32dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="32dp"
    android:topRightRadius="32dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="32dp"/>
</shape>
```

I have gotten this far.

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
Drawable customRoundedButton = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(res, R.drawable.custom_rounded_button, null);

//  customRoundedButton somehow modify corners??
// customRoundedButton.setCornerRadii(16); // What I would like to do in pseudo code
       

PiaInterfaceConfiguration.getInstance().setButtonRoundCorner(R.drawable.custom_rounded_button);
```

Problem is PiaInterfaceConfiguration only accepts drawable reference in the form of int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `PiaInterfaceConfiguration` takes only resource id `int` then you can't change these corners, you have to create another, not changeable XML or modify this class (add `int roundCorner` param and set it inside this class like you have tried with commented code)

edit: for setting corner radius you have to use [`setCornerRadius(float)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#setCornerRadius(float)) method, which belongs to `GradientDrawable`. so your `Drawable customRoundedButton` must be casted to `GradientDrawable` (even when there is solid color, gradient "feature" not used)

```
Drawable customRoundedButton = ...
if (customRoundedButton instanceof GradientDrawable) { // check just for safety
    ((GradientDrawable) customRoundedButton).setCornerRadius(22f); // float
}
```